# Locate the index of largest value in an array python

Tags: python

How would I locate the index of the largest value in an array that the user inputs? Here is what I have:

```
def main():
   numbers = eval(input("Give me an array of numbers: "))
   largest = numbers[0]
```

Comment: @ajm475du He wants the index and sorted will change said index.

Comment: I really _really_ like the attempt.

Comment: Don't want to take "credit" for the idea to use `sorted`. It was due to a previous commenter who wisely deleted that comment. I did however do a bad job of applying it. Ha.

Answer (score 1):

```
max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(numbers), key=lambda pair: pair[1])
```

This does:

- enumerate(numbers) generates (index, value) pairs
- lambda pair: pair[1] takes such a pair and returns the value part of it
- max() returns the max pair out enumerate(numbers), doing the comparison using the values from the key function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ind = numbers.index(max(numbers))
```

Comment: What if there are multiple occurrences of the maximum value?

Comment: @aj8uppal I think OP needs to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
   numbers = eval(input("Give me an array of numbers: "))
   indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == max(numbers)]
   return indices
```

**Runs as:**

```
>>> indices = main()
Give me an array of numbers: [1, 5, 9, 3, 2, 9]
>>> indices
[2, 5]
```

This code uses list comprehension to loop over the list and see where the maximum value(s) are using `max()`. This also accounts for the fact that there might be more than one of the maximum value, e.g. `[1, 5, 9, 3, 2, 9]`, `9` appears twice.