# Subarrays and counting elements of subarrays python

Tags: python

I have a program that finds the index of the largest value of an array and then from that point it splits it into two subarrays. Here's what it looks like:

```
def main():
   numbers = eval(input("Give me an array of numbers: "))
   largest = numbers[0]
   ind = numbers.index(max(numbers))
   print("Index of the largest number: ", ind)
   ar1, ar2 = numbers[0:ind], numbers[ind:]
   print("First subarray: ", ar1)
   print("Second subarray: ", ar2)
main()
```

Now I want it count the number of times the first value in the first subarray appears in the second subarray. How can I do that?

Comment: So you'll complete your entire project asking questions?

Comment: Why not post the entire assignment in one go.

Comment: I saw three answers pop up in 30 seconds

Comment: Possible _extension_ of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019773/locate-the-index-of-largest-value-in-an-array-python

Comment: Do you want the largest number to be at the end of the first list or the beginning of the second list or just be removed?

Comment: You use the code from the answers that you [receive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019773/locate-the-index-of-largest-value-in-an-array-python) but still don't accept those?

Comment: What kind of input are you expecting a user to give you for `eval(input('Give me an array of numbers: '))`? Because right now it would take a user typing _a valid Python list_ (not very user friendly) and of course is exposed to all the badness of `eval` (like the "array of number" `import os;os.system('rm -rf /')`)

Answer (score 1):

Array slicing?

```
ar1, ar2 = numbers[0:ind], numbers[ind:]
print ar1
print ar2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice:

```
print numbers[:ind], numbers[ind:]
```

`numbers[:ind]` prints elements from 0 to ind-1. `numbers[ind:]`  prints elements from ind to last element